# bind a property to the mouse in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Let's say I have a circle and a line where i bind the start of the line to the center of the circle:

```
Circle c = new Circle();
Line l = new Line();
l.startXProperty().bind(c.centerXProperty());
l.startYProperty().bind(c.centerYProperty());
```

my question: is there way to bind the end of the line (`l.endXProperty()` and  `l.endYProperty()`) to the mouse's x and y coordinates so it draws the line between the circle and the mouse?

Comment: There's no obsevable property for the mouse position. you need to use events to update the position.

Comment: @fabian thanks for your answer